# Delphi Windows Desktop App -> 513 MB memory usage on launch -> 32.1 MB after 50 mins of idle state

Tags: delphi, fastmm

we have a fairly complex Delphi App, which makes use of .NET assemblies.
We use FastMM as our Memory Manager.

We have been running into EOutOfMemory exceptions. So I have been investigating this for a while now. We were suspecting that we had some circular references between Delphi objects. Or maybe some .NET Objects holding references to Delphi objects, preventing them from being released.

So far I have not found anything that we could change on our end, which is really frustrating because obviously we have a problem somewhere.

But today by pure chance I discovered something.
When our App starts up the Task Manager reports ca. 513 MB Memory being used.
I just launched it but had to leave for lunch.
When I was back, by chance, I noticed that the App was now using only 75 MB.
Strange I thought, must have crashed or something I assumed.
No, not at all, App was functioning perfectly.
What had I done -> Nothing. Just let it run idle.
Our App is a windows desktop app. Not much is going on while its in a idle state.

So I then started to look further into this.
It is reproducible. The Memory Consumption starts to decrease in big jumps as time passes by.
After ca. 50 Mins it had reached 32.1 MB!!!

I have monitored the .NET Garbage Collector Performance Counters and there are no big changes. Therefore I suspect the problem to be on the Delphi side -> which points at FastMM.

I am no expert with FastMM though. I made sure and FullDebugMode is NOT enabled.
Has anyone else experienced something like this?
Any hints/ideas what could be misconfigured within FastMM?

Thanks a million!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you seem to have a lot of experience regarding Delphi-Memory Managers. :-). Would be very grateful if you could comment if you have had any similar experience. Thx!

Comment: You cannot address questions to specific users here, and you cannot ping them using the @ notation unless they have commented first or you are commenting on their answer. This is not a social media site, and you don't get personal tech support from your preferred user.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the info! Good to know. Well hopefully he will run into this question. I know from other SO questions that David uses his own MemoryManager and has tried several out. So his input would be quite valuable.

Comment: As opposed to the input from all of the others on this site? Good to know.

Comment: In all likelihood you are not going to get an answer from David while that comment is there because it would set a precedent encouraging other users to follow suit.

Comment: Task manager is not necessarily a good indicator of the memory in use. What memory column are you looking at with the 513 to 32 change in memory? It could well be that Windows is just paging out some memory. You should also take a look at the memory monitor form that Fast MM includes and add that to your application. Then you can watch for changes in memory.

Comment: @KenWhite if I only valued David's input I would have contacted him directly. :-) The reason I asked at StackOverflow is because I welcome and value everyone's input. Sure I made a mistake in trying to contact David via this question. I just happen to know he is very knowledgeable about the subject, but that but no means implies that there are not others who know as much or even more. I really hope you and other users understand my reasoning and can provide any helpful information you might have :-).

Comment: @Graymatter thanks for the info. Tomorrow I will look into using the memory form.
The memory used refers to 'Private Working Set'.
I don't think my mistake can set a precedence because as I understood from KenWhite, David will not receive any notification of my comment.

Comment: He won't receive a notification, but he'll see it as the first comment to this post. And you *did* make an effort to contact him directly by trying to ping him directly here. And it would be an extremely bad precedent to allow a user to dictate who (s)he prefers to get an answer from, which is why pinging users directly to get their attention isn't permitted.

Comment: Hard to comment with no knowledge of how the program is implemented. We'd just be guessing. As it stands this is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

1. The OS sometimes identifies unused RAM of an idle application, to free it for other applications, then it is not counted any more in the resource consumed by the app.
2. In such a hybrid app, most of the memory is reserved by the .Net framework, for its Garbage collector, I guess. The GC will run in idle mode, and free/compact its memory. It may be what happened. Add some logs in your app to [monitor the actual FastMM4 heap consumption](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Monitoring_Memory_Usage).
3. There may be a memory leak and you reach the 2GB limit of 32-bit process. Try to [set the 3GB flag for the exe](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Increasing_the_Memory_Address_Space). Or switch to 64-bit executable - which will make your .Net code happy. Run [FastMM4 in memory leak reporting mode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Configuring_the_Memory_Manager) to ensure the app is safe.